# make div only as wide as text content

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with this and it's driving me crazy trying to figure out why it wants to take up the full width.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPWZmP)

HTML

```
<div class="api-tile-ribbon-front">
  <div class="api-tile-ribbon-text">
    Finance<a href="#">&nbsp;&#187;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.api-tile-ribbon-text {
  color: #0C5B85;
  padding-top: 8px;
  display: inline;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.api-tile-ribbon-front {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://i60.tinypic.com/2wn5oi1.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 36px;
  max-width: 95%;
}
```

I'm using relative position so I can use the `:before` and `:after` images and I'm doing a bunch of stuff to truncate text with ellipsis.

Notice that the ribbons will automatically go to the max-width. I'd like the width to be determined by the textual content within. What is causing it to go full width and how can I stop it?

Comment: any block element, when not floated, will stretch as wide as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` or `float:left` on `.api-tile-ribbon-front` should do what you want.